# Remove selection of particular value in multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have a multi-select box that has multiple items:

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
    <option value="bar2">bar2</option>
    <option value="bar3">bar3</option>
    <option value="bar4">bar4</option>
    <option value="bar5">bar5</option>
</select>
```

Let's assume bar2, bar3 and bar5 are selected.  I want to 'unselect' bar3.

How do I use jQuery to 'unselect' just bar3, leaving bar2 and bar5 selected?

Comment: For better clarity of the question you should change it to `<select id="foo" multiple="multiple">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#foo>option[value=bar3]").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#foo option[value=bar3]').attr('selected', false);
```

Comment: you'd better use .removeAttr('selected') than .attr('selected',false). Better behavior on all browsers.